# VisualStudioの差分画面から、編集中のファイルに移動する方法

Tags: visual-studio

VisualStudioの画面で、差分画面から現在編集中のファイル（この場合は、Program.cs）に移動するショートカットキーはありませんか？

環境はMicrosoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.2です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのような機能はなさそうです。Diff機能は実在するファイルを扱っていない場合もあるからでしょうか。（gitの履歴からも任意の差分を表示することができます。）

次善策として、表示形式の Right file only を選択すると編集中のファイルの内容となります。